# How to find Profit for Category

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, mysql-workbench

My project is about a jewelery store and i try to find the profit of each product-category.
Let me be more specific

I have 3 tables which gives me the info:

SALES(salesid,productid,quantity,price)

```
salesid  productid   Quantity Price
11001    13001       4        5
11002    13002       6        10
11003    13003       5        16
.
.
11012    13012       7        15
```

RETURN(salesid,productid,date,quantity,price)

```
salesid  productid   Quantity Price
11003    13003       1        16
11007    13007       3        12
11008    13008       3        8
```

PROCUREMENT(procurementid,productid,quantity,price)

```
procurementid  productid   Quantity Price
100001         13001       10       2
100002         13002       10       2
.
. 
100012         13012       10       2
```

product_category(categoryid,category)

```
categoryid  category
1           Gold
2           Silver
.
5           Platin
```

product(Productid,categoryid)

```
Productid  categoryid
13001      1
13002      3
.
.
13010      5
```

The profit is given from this type:

```
Profit=Quantity*Price(Sell)-Quantity*Price(Return)-Quantity*Price(Procurement)
```

And now here is the problem.. I came up to this so far

```
SELECT categoryid,
       category,
       (coalesce(a.rev,0)- coalesce(b.ret,0),
                           coalesce(c.cost,0)) AS profit
FROM product category AS g
    JOIN product AS h ON g.categoryid = h.categoryid
    JOIN
      (SELECT categoryid,
              sum(quantity*price) AS rev
       FROM sales AS a,
            product AS b
       WHERE a.productid = b.productid
       GROUP BY categoryid) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT cartegoryid,
              sum(quantity*price) AS ret
       FROM RETURN AS a ,
                      product AS b
       WHERE a.productid = b.productid
       GROUP BY categoryid) b ON a.categoryid = b.categoryid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT categoryid,
              sum(quantity*price) AS cost
       FROM procurement AS a,
            product AS b
       WHERE a.productid = b.productid
       GROUP BY categoryid) c ON a.categoryid = c.categoryid ,
    product AS d,
    procurement AS e
WHERE MONTH(f.date) = MONTH(e.date)
  AND YEAR(date) = 2013
```

[sorry for the align i am new to the site dont know how to copy paste code well(:D)]
wahtever when i do this it comes to a state like

```
categoryid  category  profit
1           Gold      -100
2           Silver    -100
.
5           Platin    -100
```

dont know where is the problem...i made a lot of changes and switches but nothing came up...any suggestion would be so helpfull.Thank u in advane

Answer (score 0):

Initially looks like your profit formula has an extra comma in it.
this

```
(coalesce(a.rev,0) - coalesce(b.ret,0),coalesce(c.cost,0)) as profit
```

should be this

```
coalesce(a.rev,0) - coalesce(b.ret,0) - coalesce(c.cost,0) AS profit
```

Few more issues with this query

- Right before the where clause, after you join the cost subquery, you add product and procurement tables but don't join them. This will cause a cartesian join which will throw off your results.
- In the where clause you don't specify which tables date field you want to use. `AND YEAR(date) = 2013` should be `e.date` or `f.date`. That should have given you an error if you tried to run it.
- `WHERE MONTH(f.date) = MONTH(e.date)` which table is f.date referring to? You didn't give an alias of `f` to any table.
- You join in procurement and use its date field to filter results by month, but none of your revenue, returns, and cost subquery totals take dates into account. This will throw off your results.